# iOS System.Net.Http: No such file or directory

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, portable-class-library, dotnet-httpclient

Working with a Xamarin iOS app using HttpClient. The app works fine in iOS 8, but iOS 9+ returns null reference exceptions when using HttpClient.PostAsync. The only clue I have is this in my log files:

*System.Net.Http.dll.mdb failed: No such file or directory*

I'm not linking, and nothing I can notice has changed. Any ideas?

edit: I also tried removing / reinstalling Microsoft.Net.Http via NuGet but:

- it never actually appears in any reference list of any project
- above error does not in Microsoft namespace

Comment: Same here. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

An .mdb file is for debugging an assembly - while inconvenient, it was not the issue. I ended up reverting to a previous commit which fixed the issue, which leads me to believe it was some corruption of my project files. Thank god for source control!

Comment: After several hours scouring for a solution, in my case it was also simply some sort of corruption that was solved by reverting to a previous version!